# Can winrar "Delete files after archiving" files restore from hard disk?

Tags: archiving, winrar

winrar has an "delete files after archiving" option. we know even permanently deleted files can be restored when the laptop stolen or sold to anyone malicious. that's why we know we should clean empty disk area time to time to be safe over our datas.
but how winrar's "delete files after archiving" spec works? is it imitate the windows classic shift+delete option (so it is not healthy for privacy) or it has another method to delete it over and over like "file shredder" ?

thanks.

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCWGf.png)

Answer (score 1):

#### How does `winrar`'s "delete files after archiving" work?

There are different options when using the command line version.:

> Switch `-DF` - delete files after archiving
>
> Move files to archive. This switch in combination with the command a
> performs the same action as the command m.

Source [Switch -DF - delete files after archiving - WinRAR Documentation](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPSwDF.htm)

and:

> Switch `-DW` - wipe files after archiving
>
> Delete files after archiving. Before deleting file data are
> overwritten by zero bytes to prevent recovery of deleted files.
>
> Please be aware that such approach is designed for usual hard disks,
> but may fail to overwrite the original file data on solid state disks,
> as result of SSD wear levelling technology and more complicated data
> addressing.

Source: [Switch -DW - wipe files after archiving - WinRAR Documentation](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPSwDW.htm)

So it depends on what command line switches you use. If you are worried about privacy you should use the second option.

When using the GUI version of winrar then after selecting "delete files after archiving" you need to go to the "Options" tab, where you can select which delete mode you want to use:

[image: winrar gui options tab]

Comment: Thank you for you reply but how about in windows? is winrar in windows overwritten by zero bytes to prevent recovery of deleted files?